# Strange compilation issue boost/ssl

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, openssl, asio

I'm migrating my app from boost 1.72 to boost 1.75.

The code was working with 1.72. but not for 1.75

I got this strange error when including boost/asio/ssl:

```
boost/asio/ssl/impl/host_name_verification.ipp : 
error X509_check_ip_asc was not declared in this scope
```

Have you any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, you're using a too old version of OpenSSL. [`X509_check_ip_asc`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/X509_check_ip_asc.html) was added in OpenSSL 1.0.2.

Comment: I'm using openssl 1.1.1h